# How do Microsoft Word and Excel run without any installation?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2003

I was having a discussion on bookmarks in Word with a friend, and he suggested me to check out his implementation of a query in Word. Since I did not have Microsoft Word installed, I told him I don't have Word so I won't be able to test it.

To this, he mentioned that he'll send the executables and it will work - I argued that without an installation this will fail.

I was rather shocked when he sent me the **standalone executables** and on running them, Word actually launched and I was able to use almost every functionality o_0

How's this possible? I've never installed Microsoft Office on my system, this isn't any "portable" app or [VMWare ThinStall](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/) ( [thanks nhinkle](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/609889#609889), didn't know about this).

There are absolutely no  Microsoft Office related files - except for `winword.exe` and `excel.exe`.

Curiously even Microsoft Excel works fine with just the **standalone executable**.

`winword.exe` size is about 39 MB, and `excel.exe` size is just 35kb, which makes it even more strange.

[image]

I'm running on Windows XP, the files were from Office 2003.

---

I was discussing this on [Chat](http://chat.superuser.com) prior to posting, here's [the conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/conversation/standalone-word-excel)

Comment: were you also able to create new documents ?

Comment: @Shark yes, was able to create new documents, save documents, edit existing ones

Comment: Are they running the on-line Live versions?

Comment: @Sathya then I guess thats very charitable of MS  :) Can you ask your friend how did he make the executable ? I have office 2010 and would like to try this

Comment: @Dennis - No, no online/Live365 versions - just standard Office 2003 install

Comment: @Shark - he didn't do anything - he just sent me the `winword.exe` and `excel.exe` files to me, I double clicked them and it ran - no office installer popups et al

Comment: @Sathya - Did you see any Thinstall-related folders anywhere in the /Documents and Settings/Local Settings or /Application Data folders? I've seen similar versions for even something like Photoshop CS3 as small as that winword.exe file.

Comment: @lsxek there is `Thinstall\Office 2003` under `Application Data\`

Comment: Only 39MB, eh?  Pretty impressive.  That's only twice the size of my first two hard drives put together.  Only about 10 times the size of a functioning Linux kernel.  How did they get it so small, anyway?

Comment: @harpo even more impressive is that Excel is just 35kb

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[VMWare ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/) is what you are seeing. I've done some testing while it was still called Thinstall and then VMware bought it. It's nice because it allows you to use Office 2003 / Office 2007 / Office 2010 and many more applications like IE6, IE7, IE8 next to each other.

Basically procedure to create it looks like this:

1. You install yourself a clean system.
   (VM machine is perfect for this)
2. You run Thinapp do to a system snapshot.
   Then you install application
3. You run Thinapp again and it finds the
   changes with last snapshot and packs
   it up.

This even gets better. You can install `NET, Java` after the first snapshot and then application that uses `NET` or `Java`. And then use the application created with ThinApp on system that doesn't have `NET` or `Java` Installed.

Just to add the size difference is because Excel will use Word packed files. If you move away Word application Excel won't work.

Comment: Interesting - @nhinkle had mentioned about ThinApp but I had dismissed it earlier. Thanks for the nice explanation

Comment: Ye it's nice but you need to pay for ThinApp licenses and Office licenses too ;-) So double costs

Comment: Wish I hadn't had school all day, else I would've posted this and could've gotten all those upvotes ;). @Sathya does it look like it is indeed ThinApp? Every time I've used it before it's taken a few minutes to open and seen a little window pop up saying "Launching _application name_... Powered By VMware"

Comment: That window can be turned off with configuration (at least while i was testing Thinstall.

Comment: @nhinkle yes, indeed - but as I had mentioned to you on chat - there were no popups whatsoever. Accepting this answer. Thanks @Madboy!

Answer (score 9):

Though my suggestion was originally denied ;), based on your observations I was probably correct after all: your friend must have had a copy of Microsoft Office which has been virtualized with [VMware ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/).

First, I verified that a copy of the regular `winword.exe` and `excel.exe` would not work by themselves. I installed Office 2003 in a Windows XP VM, then copied them over to a different VM which had never had Office installed. Both applications failed to run.

Based on your comment that "there is `Thinstall\Office 2003` under `Application Data`", it seems most likely that this is the explanation. Here is how you can check:

- Remove the directory `%APPDATA%\Thinstall\Office 2003`
- Run the Office executable that your friend sent you
- Check back in `%APPDATA%\Thinstall\` and see if the Office 2003 folder has reappeared. If it has, the application is definitely using ThinApp.

We use a ThinApp-wrapped version of MATLAB at my university; it has to have a .dat file present with all of the program contents. Depending on the requirements of the application though, this may not be necessary, which appears to be the case with these office programs before.

Essentially, what ThinApp does is it virtualizes the entire directory structure and registry for the application. This allows for the application to be portable and to run without interfering with the system. ThinApp also supports network licensing, so if you have an application (like MATLAB in our case) that your organization has a finite number of licenses for, it can check in with the licensing server before launching the application, and only launch it if it successfully acquires a license.

That directory in `%APPDATA%` contains the folders which ThinApp virtualizes for the application. Anything that would normally be in Word's `%APPDATA%` folder, like personal settings, gets saved here instead. Because of this, no matter where you launch the executable from on your computer, the settings will be preserved *on that machine*. They do not get transfered with the packaged application itself however. This becomes relevant when trying to reset the settings for an application which is packed with ThinApp, as the usual method of deleting its folder in `%APPDATA%\Program Name` doesn't work - you have to find its virtualized folder.

Answer (score 3):

It's not because the application is called WINWORD.EXE and the icon is the same that it is the exact same application that is shipped in Office. All Office applications have a digital signature. Right-click the winword.exe and excel.exe files and check if there is a Digital Signatures tab. You will notice those applications don't have a signature at all let alone one from Microsoft.

The applications you have are probably self-extracting executables, which contain modified files of Word 2003 so it will run without being installed. If you have 7-zip installed you can try to unpackage winword.exe and see for yourself.

Comment: you're right about it not having a digital signature tab - though extracting it using 7zip fails.

Comment: This is not ordinary packed application. ThinApp doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft itself offers a "portable" version of Office for validation: http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/portable-microsoft-office-2010

Comment: That's a pirated version

Comment: I didn't saw that! Sorry! Changed the link.

Comment: @Sathya, actually technically your version you received from your friend is pirated as well.  Also I believe that starter version are open to the public, but could be wrong.

Comment: "Office Starter is available only as preloaded software on select new PCs with the option of upgrading to the full Office suites at any time."  Actually I was wrong.  [Ref site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/starter/)

Comment: @KronoS I very much doubt it is pirated - but then I could be wrong

Comment: @sathya I'm not saying that yours friends software is actually pirated but more rather the fact that HE sent you copies to use for free becomes a violation of the EULA I believe.

Comment: @KronoS Of course, that goes without saying :)